# Return std::tuple and move semantics / copy elision

Tags: c++, c++17, move-semantics

I have the following factory function:

```
auto factory() -> std::tuple<bool, std::vector<int>>
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);

    return { true, vec };
}

auto [b, vec] = factory();
```

In the return statement is `vec` considered an `xvalue` or `prvalue` and therefore moved or copy elided?

My guess is no, because the compiler, when list-initializing the `std::tuple` in the return statement, still doesn't know that vec is going to be destroyed. So maybe an explicit std::move is required:

```
auto factory() -> std::tuple<bool, std::vector<int>>
{
    ...
    return { true, std::move(vec) };
}

auto [b, vec] = factory();
```

Is it that really required?

Comment: You have to do `return { true, std::move(vec) };`.

Comment: Yup, this is required here to be sure that the vector will be moved. But compilers are mostly smart enough to optimize the copy away

Comment: @bartop: Compilers are *not allowed* to "optimize the copy away".

Comment: @NicolBolas Actually, they are allowed to do *anything*, as long as the observable behaviour does not change. Would be creating a copy observable (provided there are no observable side effects in constructor or destructor)?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, since the `allocator::construct/destruct` and the copy constructor of the elements of `vector` are all observable side effects.

Comment: @NicolBolas I see, have overseen OS, which can observe: More memory requested, data in memory changes. That's the point, isn't it? Or is there even more involved?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> In the return statement is `vec` considered an xvalue or prvalue and therefore moved or copy elided?

`vec` is *always* an lvalue. Even in the simple case:

```
std::vector<int> factory() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    return vec;
}
```

That is *still* returning an lvalue. It's just that we have [special rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#1) that say that we just ignore the copy in this case when we're returning the name of an automatic object (and another [special rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3) in the case that copy elision doesn't apply, but we still try to move from lvalues).

But those special rules *only* apply to the `return object;` case, they don't apply to the `return {1, object};` case, no matter how similar it might look. In your code here, that would do a copy, because that's what you asked for. If you want to do a move, you must do:

```
return {1, std::move(object)};
```

And in order to avoid the move, you must do:

```
auto factory() -> std::tuple<bool, std::vector<int>>
{
    std::tuple<bool, std::vector<int>> t;

    auto& [b, vec] = t;
    b = true;
    vec.push_back(1);
    vec.push_back(2);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that in the "avoid moving" variant, the trailing return type *can* be omitted entirely...

Comment: One-liner variant: `return std::make_tuple(true, std::vector<int>({1, 2}));` not sure, now, if any moving involved on *constructing* the return type, though...

Comment: The more interesting point of my one-liner, though, is if I reintroduced moving - which we originally wanted to avoid, i. e. chances are that we cannot use this construct for given purpose...

Comment: Thanks a lot, a very sharp explanation. I tested all the four versions both with GCC and MSVC, the behavior was the expected one.The one-liner of @Aconcagua is the same as the version with std::move (a part the different constructor).