# C++ : create a tuple with vector of strings

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following API to be implemented:

```
tuple<vector<string>, ItemStatus> SomeFcn() const
{
    vector<string> result_item;
    return tuple(result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL );
}
```

But it does not compile and compile output is not clear at all

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)’
  436 |         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
      |         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Something is wrong at tuple instance creation. I have this code compiled with `-std=c++17`. `ItemStatus` is an enum class.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Your question is tagged with C++11 (which does not have class template argument deduction) whereas you mention you are compiling with C++17: what language level are you using?

Comment: I compile it with g++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g3

Comment: I have no compiler at hand currently, so I cannot test this: try wrapping ˋresult_itemˋ with parentheses in the return call.

Comment: Did you simply try `return {result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL };` ?

Comment: Have you tried [`std::make_tuple()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) yet?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, see: https://wandbox.org/permlink/QSlMKwScu5dLaEdn.  Maybe you just need to remove that `const`, if it's a non-member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write like this instead, assuming ItemStatus is an enum

```
std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>, ItemStatus> SomeFcn() const
{
  std::vector<std::string> result_item;
  return std::make_tuple(result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL );
}
```

(* i don't like leaving namespace out *)

Comment: @Dmitry, then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer?

Comment: ups, sorry - I upvoted but forgot to accept...my fault

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you have three options:

- [Copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) :

```
return {result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL };
```

- Create a tuple object ([make_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple)) (AndersK's answer):

```
return std::make_tuple(result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL );
```

- Use [tuple ctor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple) :

```
return std::tuple<std::vector<std::string>, ItemStatus>{result_item, ItemStatus::ACTUAL };
```

Comment: Would using `std::move` improve (or harm) the performance of any of these (assuming `result_item` is in fact a huge `vector`, since a function that always returns an empty one seems kind of pointless)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger: It's already a return statement. The compiler knows that local variables go out of scope and can safely be moved from.

Comment: As @MSalters said, I wouldn't do that. In addition, highly related with copy elision and NRVO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: Just to be explicit: you don't want to call `std::move` on the return expression. Calling `std::move` on the arguments to `std::make_tuple` on the other hand would make sense.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thinking about it more, and seeing that there was no anwer on that yet, I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64541229/stdmove-in-sub-expressions-of-return-statement

Comment: @MSalters: Yeah, that's what I meant. `std::move` of the result of `std::make_tuple` is clearly pointless (copy-elision/RVO handles that), but whether it helps avoid deep-copies of the `vector` wasn't clear; can the compiler adequately optimize the call `std::make_tuple` with the knowledge that `result_item` is expiring, or is that knowledge not available or too complex for most compilers to handle, so `std::move` would be indicated?

Comment: @Jose: Looks like you should use `move` though; obviously you shouldn't `move` the `tuple` itself (copy-elision handles that), but the items being added to the `tuple` [should be `move`d to avoid being copied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51521031/364696).