# std::move in sub-expressions of return statement

Tags: c++, c++17, rvo

It's [well-known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986673/c11-rvalues-and-move-semantics-confusion-return-statement) that you shouldn't use `std::move` when returning a local variable:

```
std::vector<int> return_vector(void)
{
    std::vector<int> tmp {1,2,3,4,5};
    return std::move(tmp); // DON'T DO THIS
}
```

But what about the case where your `return` expression contains `tmp` as a sub-expression?

```
std::tuple<vector<int>, size_t> return_tuple() const
{
    std::vector<int> tmp {1,2,3,4,5};
    return std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp), tmp.size());
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know there's a bonus question hiding in there.

Comment: Don't do this! The order in which `std::move(tmp)` and `tmp.size()` are evaluated is unspecified, so you may invoke a function on a moved-from object which may produce wrong results

Comment: @dave: In this case, yeah, the example could use improvement; probably best to write the example as: `std::vector<int> tmp {1,2,3,4,5};`, `auto size = tmp.size();`, `return std::make_tuple(std::move(tmp), auto);` just to remove that bit of bother from consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return std::tuple and move semantics / copy elision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521031/return-stdtuple-and-move-semantics-copy-elision)

Comment: @Rane: First time I've used the close privilege to close my own question :D

Comment: @dave: You win the bonus.

Comment: @dave: It’s not the `std::move` itself that’s the problem—`std::move` doesn’t move anything—but it’s true that the parameter might be initialized from the rvalue before the other argument is evaluated.